# Xamarin PCL library and Sqlite data storage

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, xamarin, cross-platform

I'm developing a cross platform application with Xamarin for Android, iOS and Windows Phone. I'm creating a PCL library that contains all my business logic including calls to my REST API. For now this seem to work fine, however, I need to store bits of information in a persistent space, such as API authentication keys etc, and I figured I might as well use Sqlite for this, it seems to be supported on all three platforms.

The problem I'm running into is that `System.Data` and `Mono.Data.Sqlite` don't seem to be available within the context of a PCL project.

Even if my PCL library can't, or doesn't, link with the required assemblies, I should at least be able to use the references (through `using`) in my PCL library, right? I mean, I should be able to have the application be responsible for creating a database connection and then use dependency injection to inject that connection into my library. But seems I can't even make references in my code to any the `System.Data` and `Mono.Data.Sqlite` at all.

How do I abstract my data layer in a PCL library with Xamarin for Android, iOS and Windows Phone?

[1] http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/system.data/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [SQLite.Net.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Async-PCL/). You can then use DI to inject the platform implementation ([ISQLitePlatform](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/master/src/SQLite.Net/Interop/ISQLitePlatform.cs)) into PCL side. Another option is to use [SQLite-Net PCL](http://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) if you don't want to use DI.

Answer (score 0):

I would be looking at using Inversion of Control technique so I have an interface or abstract class that is PCL compatible then a platform specific implementation of this class. At startup of the application the correct platform specific object is initiated and then passed into the PCL compatible library.

Comment: Just a further thought, you should not need to write your data access per platform just one implementation should be sufficient maybe using something like SQLite.Net library. (grab through nuget).
The library is not PCL compliant itself hence using the ioc technique

Comment: I was already thinking of using dependency injection for this. This way the host application is responsible for obtaining an SQLite instance which would be passed into the PCL instance so it can perform operations on it. You mention to use an interface or abstract class. Of which project would these be part? My problem is currently that even though my PCL library doesn't need to "link" with any of requirements, it does need to know about the SQLite objects and method signatures. How do you propose I do this?

Comment: I think this is what you're getting at? http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/#PCL_Example

Comment: My apologies for not getting back to you sooner. Yes that guide is pretty good and you could certainly achieve what you are trying to do by following it.